# UISearchBar Customization

Tags: ios, ios7, uisearchbar

I'm trying to customize UISearchBar but I"m having a hard time with it.

[image]

This is what my searchbar looks like currently. What I want to be able to do is set a uiimage on the entire uisearchbar. I tried setSearchFieldBackgroundImage but it does not affect the text field part of the searchbar. How can I put an image in the white part? I also want to extend the white part to the edge to have equal margins on all sides.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226922/uitextfield-within-uisearchbar-failing-after-ios-7-upgrade/19227102#19227102

Comment: use UITextfield and put it in UIVIew() .

Answer (score 0):

for the image purpose u could use this one,dont forget to import Quartzcore framework

```
[searchbar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"base_200x50.png"]];
    [searchbar setTranslucent:YES];
    UITextField *txtSearchField = [searchbar valueForKey:@"_searchField"];
    [txtSearchField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"base_200x50.png"]]];
    [txtSearchField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
    txtSearchField.layer.borderWidth = 8.0f;
    txtSearchField.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f;
    txtSearchField.layer.borderColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
```

and to extend textfeild u can set frame of txtSearchField.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this may help you:

Pattern image I used:

[image]

```
@IBOutlet weak var sbSearchBar: UISearchBar!

// if you wan to set background color for searchbar, except field
func setupSearchbarBackgroundImage() -> Void {

    sbSearchBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "pattern2"), for: UIBarPosition.any, barMetrics: UIBarMetrics.default)

}
```

Result:

[image]

```
func setupSearchbar() -> Void {
    // if you wan to set background color for field only
    if let textfield = sbSearchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField {

        textfield.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "pattern2")!)

    }
}
```

Here is result:

[image]