# Why does UISearchBar's UITextField not respond like a normal UITextField to a rightview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uitextfield, uisearchbar

I'm having trouble implementing a `UISearchBar` whose `UITextField` has a rightview. I tried on a normal `UITextField` the following:

```
self.textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(10, 30, 300, 30)];
self.textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
self.textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever;
self.textField.delegate = self;

UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 150, 44)];
[button setBackgroundColor: [UIColor redColor]];

[self.textField setRightViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];
[self.textField setRightView:button];

[self.view addSubview:self.textField];
```

And as expected, it generates the following:
[image: UITextField with RightView]

I need the `UISearchBar's` `UITextField` to be have the same -- so I decided to subclass `UISearchBar`.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if (self) {

        // This is simply here to make sure that we are able to get the textfield
        [self setSearchTextPositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0, 0)];

        // Function that helps us get the textfield
        UITextField *textField = [self textFieldGetter];

        // This will be true if we call setSearchTextFieldPositionAdjust
        if (textField) {

            // Verify that the textfield exists...
            NSLog(@"The textField does exist");

            UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 150, 44)];
            [button setBackgroundColor: [UIColor redColor]];

            // Set the clear button to be off
            textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever;

            // Make the button the rightview of the textfield
            [textField setRightView:button];
            [textField setRightViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

But it does not work and the `UISearchBar` simply looks like:

[image: Image of UISearchBar]

The `UITextFieldGetter` is in essence something very similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19227102).

Why isn't the `UITextField` the same in the `UISearchBar` as it is normally? Is there a way that I can get the same effect programmatically? Or if it can't be done, is there a way that I can change the `UITextField's` width once I know the button is there?

Comment: Why not just write your own version of UISearchBar?